# laravel toastr js notification shows on every page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, notifications

In my controller :

```
    public function showFreelancers(Request $request)
    {
        $authUser = Auth::user();
        session()->put('success','Item created successfully.');
        return view('freelancer/index',compact('authUser'));
    }
```

I have only one `session()->put('success','Item created successfully.');` in my entire controller.

My layout page have the below code just above from . And from below all js files.

```
<script>

  @if(Session::has('success'))
        toastr.success("{{ Session::get('success') }}");
  @endif

  @if(Session::has('info'))
        toastr.info("{{ Session::get('info') }}");
  @endif

  @if(Session::has('warning'))
        toastr.warning("{{ Session::get('warning') }}");
  @endif

  @if(Session::has('error'))
        toastr.error("{{ Session::get('error') }}");
  @endif

</script>
```

When i hit `Route::get('/','FreelancerController@showFreelancers')->name('FreelancerIndex');` i get the message which is okay ! But when i open another route i get the exact same notification.

What i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually pushing it into the session permanently rather than temporarily. You can use

```
session()->flash('key', 'value')
```

Now it will only flash it on the next page, rather than every page. You will also need to clear your session after changing it to `flash()`

Comment: This solution did not solve my problem

Comment: @SospeterMong'are You are not OP, write a question and maybe someone will help you